# How to use host machine shell PWD as WORKDIR using Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a docker run command :

```
docker run -v $(shell pwd):$(shell pwd):rw -w $(shell pwd) node:14-alpine /bin/sh -c "npm run test"
```

In the above command using bindmount and making that same directory (host machine PWD) as WORDIR inside the container.

Now the same thing I want to do using Dockerfile i.e. make container WORKDIR same as current shell PWD of host machine.

Or rephrasing it differently: how to access current shell PWD inside Dockerfile.

Comment: There is no such concept as *current shell PWD* when you build Docker image, only Dockerfile and "context". Check https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#extended-description

Comment: A Docker image is generally intended to be reusable in different environments; you wouldn't usually build an image that has a dependency on a specific host environment.  It's very typical to use simple directory names like `/app` in an image.  What would you do if you did know the actual host directory here?

Comment: Your point is correct, but this is very specific use case. Using istanbulJS and cypress, inside container it'll generate code coverage, the resulting lcov.info have path with respect to container directory structure, now with bind mount I got coverage report in host machine file system, but sonar can not map it to original source code present in host machine at the time of scanning. Hence I thought of having same dir structure inside my app container (React app), so that istanbulJS will instrument code as per host machine dir.

Comment: Consider doing a post-processing of the report files with `sed 's|/A/PATH/IN/CONTAINER|/A/DESIRED/PATH|'`, maybe even you can end up using some relative path, like `./` in your substitution.

Comment: this seems to be a good solution, let me try and see if this will solve the issue.

Comment: I tried and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you need is to create a path inside your Docker image matching one that you have when (and where) you call `docker build`. This way, I'd suggest you use [build-time variables](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg) and make the path with `RUN mkdir -p $SOME_NAME_OF_YOUR_CHOICE`.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way so that I can have same dir structure as my host machine, at the time of istanbul js instrumentation.